# How does one add a field to a mongoDB document using mongoose with a strict : false schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, model, mongoose

I'm trying to automate some data processing tasks for my IT firm. I need to be able to cycle through a collection, find all documents with a given numerical ID (not ObjectID), and add them as an array field to documents from a different collection. This is how I'm attempting it:

```
voter.find({"District" : {"$eq" : "D"}}).stream()
    .on('data', function (doc) {

      var reg = new RegExp(doc._doc.Registration_Number, "i");
      history.find({"Registration_Number" : {"$eq" : Number(doc._doc.Registration_Number)}}, function (err, docs) {
        var arr = new Array(); //In the context of a single voter!
        u.each(docs, function (v, k) {
          if (v) {
            console.log(v._doc.ElectionDate); //Only if Registration_Number of voter matches history doc.
            arr.push(v._doc.ElectionDate);
          }
        });

        //Now we have array of history
        doc.update({"Registration_Number" : {"$eq" : Number(doc._doc.Registration_Number)}}, {VotingHistory : arr}, {multi : true}, function (error, num) {
          if (err) console.log("SOMETHING WENT VERY WRONG");
          console.log(dat);
        });

      });
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log("Ending voter stream.");
    })
```

The update callback never fires, though I've tried a voter.find() with the same query and it returns exactly one voter every time I use a valid Registration_Number. I need to automate this with unpredictable field names, so I'd like to avoid using schemas if at all possible. My current schema is bare bones:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var voter = new mongoose.Schema({}, {
  strict: false,
  collection: 'voters'
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('voter', voter);
```

Anyone have an idea how I can make this work? This question is similar to quite a few others, but every one I've seen is answered with model.update(), which I can not seem to get working.

My code runs for a while printing out only ElectionDate, and the update callback never fires. When I let it run it ends on this error:

```
MY_DIRECTORY\THE_APP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2008
      oldCb(error, result ? result.result : { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 });
      ^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at callback (MY_DIRECTORY\THE_APP\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2008:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (MY_DIRECTORY\THE_APP\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:160:11)
    at Object._onImmediate (MY_DIRECTORY\THE_APP\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mquery\lib\utils.js:137:16)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:354:15)
15 Oct 09:13:31 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution, though not pretty, was to modify the doc._doc and use the overwrite: true option in the update function. Full code:

```
voter.find({"District" : {"$eq" : "D"}}).stream()
    .on('data', function (doc) {

      var reg = new RegExp(doc._doc.Registration_Number, "i");
      history.find({"Registration_Number" : {"$eq" : Number(doc._doc.Registration_Number)}}, function (err, docs) {
        var arr = new Array(); //In the context of a single voter!
        u.each(docs, function (v, k) {
          if (v) {
            console.log(v._doc.ElectionDate); //Only if Registration_Number of voter matches history doc.
            arr.push(v._doc.ElectionDate);
          }
        });

        //Now we have array of history
        doc._doc.VotingHistory = arr;
        console.log(doc._doc);
        voter.update({ "Registration_Number" : doc._doc.Registration_Number}, doc._doc, {overwrite : true }, function (er, num) {
          if (er) console.log("ERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");
          console.log("NUMBER AFFECTED (should always be 1) : " + num);
        });

      });
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log("Ending voter stream.");
    });
```